# Video transmission over wifi using UDP/packet injection

Tags: stream, udp, protocols, packet

Hey Stackoverflow community :)

Im looking into making a camera stream video from a an RC device into a computer using wifi.

After considering all of the options I had Im left with two:

1. use UDP to transfer video in packets
2. use packet injection and packet sniffing on the receiving device.

I was wondering what are the pros and cons of each method (for that specific purpose of video transmission)?
after looking around I found many implementations for both ways but nowhere have they specified why one is better than the other.

few things that I have not mentioned:

1. I know UDP does not have error correction which can make the video weird- I dont care about the quality of the video as long as it will be recognizeable.
   I dont want to use connection based protocol (TPC, etc)- I dont want to wait for handshake when I get disconnected.

thanks :)

Comment: *"After considering all of the options I had Im left with two:"* - strange choice, especially "packet injection" does not make any sense for me. It would be useful to know how you came up with exactly these options. In general: UDP is useful if you need real time and packet loss is acceptable - use a codec which can cope with packet loss then, like having each UDP datagram contain an independent frame. TCP is useful if you don't need full real-time, i.e. a few seconds lag would be acceptable. But the advantage is that it can you can use highly optimizing codecs for compression.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering :)

How I came up with those options:
1. I have defined set of requirements  for the system, some of which are : low latency, be connectionless (so if I got too far I wont have to wait for handshake to be reestablished), and I want to use wifi for the transmission (due to ease of use, and availibility of parts and their prices compare to other means).

like I said, TCP is not an option, if you have any other ideas rather than UDP/packet injection Id be more than happy to hear.

Comment: To address the packet injection - like I said, I have yet to play with it and thats why I came here, I wanted to know which would be best for my purpose as I found implementation of both online. 

here is the packet injection video transmission: https://github.com/jeanlemotan/esp32-cam-fpv

and here be UDP https://hackaday.com/2015/06/13/wifibroadcast-makes-wifi-fpv-video-more-like-analog/

there are many more online, yet none of them address the reason behind choosing one way over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to do a similar thing. My take on this is basically when you use the wifi cards in monitor mode (i.e. using packet sniffing/injection) you don't actually need to be connected to that network. Typically, you still need to be connected to an Access point as a client then you can communicate using UDP through that connection. But, in this case, the UDP messages are routed to the Wifi cards and the packets are injected out without being associated with any client.  Then, any 'client' just has to sniff or listen on that same channel to get the transmission. So the benefit is not only does UDP not check for lost frames/etc, but also in this case  you don't need to be connected to the network to get the packets.

In my case, this is preferable, since basically you will need to connect to the AP in the former case and that would require more capable hardware on the receiver side typically (more range is needed for the association part since you need to send messages back over TCP essentially to get it connected).

FYI here are the links/repos I am using and it also is a reference to what I am talking about
https://docs.px4.io/master/en/tutorials/video_streaming_wifi_broadcast.html
https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast

I am using an off the shelf 'solution' in the short term, the Accsoon Cineye Air, which basically transmits HDMI 300ft line of sight over WiFi. You need an android phone to receive it, and basically I'm using the Vysor application (paid version is $40) to mirror the screen to my desktop. It works, but the latency is still more than I want : 60ms at least from the cineeye, so you can drive it around but its not as quick as DJI which is around 30-40ms ), which is my goal.

Comment: Thank you Jacob! are you trying to achieve long range ditial fpv datalink?
Also - which wifi cards are you using?

Comment: @iSoda, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I am using these wifi cards: ALFA 
 WUS036ACH, Intel AX210NGW, Ralink RT5572 since these cards all have the support I need as far as I know. I'm fairly certain about the latter two cards, but all the information I can find is pointing to using the ALFA one

Comment: Thanks again Jacob!
Is there a way I can keep in touch with you outside of stackoverflow?
I sort of gave up on FPV for now, but I am developing my own controller (in arduino, something like Skydroid T12 with a little screen for settings, not FPV) which will output via usb to raspberry pi ground station which would in turn handle all the communication (via UDP packets.)
What camera did you plan to be using? does it output h.264 or would the Pi compress it and then send it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can add my linkedIn here https://www.linkedin.com/in/rameyjm/. FYI I have changed strategies to utilizing a set of 802.11ah modules, basically long range wifi on 900MHz bands. I'm using the SX-NEWAH-EVK to do it with two RPI4s https://www.silextechnology.com/connectivity-solutions/embedded-wireless/sx-newah. For the camera, I am open to a lot of different options. I saw the UDP stuff wants an h264 encoded cam, but it is not easy to find anymore, they want us to do it in SW. So i'm using a different low light camera, it doesn't output h264 just raw RGB